# Why doesn't 'half' only modify countable nouns?

Tags: countability

Why doesn't 'half' only modify countable nouns? According to the definition, isn't 'half' also number?

Comment: Example sentence, please.

Comment: A half is a fraction.

Comment: @BillJ As stated, fractions are *quantifiers* not modifiers. Even if you insist that quantifiers are a kind of modifier, you still have to accept that you must quantify something in order to be able to apply a fraction to it. I've responded to all of your comments only for the reason that I don't want the OP to be misled by your unsound reasoning.

Comment: @Astralbee It's your answer that will mislead the OP, when you say "It does only work with countable nouns" (though I see you've now amended your answer)  The OP asked the very simple question  "Why doesn't 'half' only modify countable nouns", which is a fair question since "half" does indeed modify non-count nouns. And, yes, "half" **is**a modifier, irrespective of what else it may be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesn't 'half' only modify countable nouns?

Fractions *quantify* nouns. A quantifier has a similar function to a modifier. If something is truly uncountable then it cannot be quantified, but as most uncountable nouns, such as liquids, can be measured and broken down into quantities then you can use a quantifier like 'half' with them because it is actually being applied to the measure, not the uncountable noun itself, whether you specifically mention that measure or simply imply it.

For example, 'water' can refer to *all* water:

- Water is a chemical compound.

However, you can also refer to a *specific quantity of water*:

- I have *a glass* of water.

The water in the glass can be measured, therefore you can say:

- I have drunk half my water.

Using the possessive "my" indicates that it is a specific quantity of water. The measurement (a glass, a bottle, whatever) is implied. You are therefore applying the fraction to the countable measurement (a glass, glasses, a bottle, or bottles etc).

But even using 'water' as an uncountable noun, you could still 'measure' it - for example, water is two parts hydrogen to one part oxygen, therefore you could say:

> Two-thirds of water is hydrogen.

'Two-thirds' is a fraction just like 'half'. If the chemical composition was different, as in the case of hydrogen peroxide, you could say "half" of it was hydrogen, because *in any given measure*, that is its chemical composition. Again, the fraction is being applied to a *hypothetical quantity* which in turn represents all quantities.

Comment: I don't think I agree with this answer.  It must be quantifiable, yes, but it need not be countable (at least if we by "countable" we are referring to the grammatical distinction between countable and non-countable nouns). Most non-countable nouns can also be used as countable ("a water" = a glass of water).  But when we say "half of the water [that was here previously] has evaporated" then although the water is quantifiable, we're not using "water" as a countable noun.  Things are often quantifiable without being countable,  e.g. "I have two litres of water".

Comment: "A glass of water" is countable. You absolutely **can** measure it, but you don't need to in order to say "half a glass". In your examples, all the water would be measurable, and that is exactly my point. I think you're getting confused because "**a** glass" is countable as one, but it might contain, for example, 450ml. It doesn't matter if you measure it by glasses (1) or millilitres (450) you can still say you drank "half of **the** water". If you can't measure the whole, you can't measure half.

Comment: It's true that a glass of water is countable.  It's just that, in the phrase "a glass of water", the word "water" is being used as a non-countable noun.  It's also true that the water is measurable.  But this is different from asserting that we only use "half" with countable nouns, since the term "countable" has a distinctive meaning in grammar.

Comment: @rjpond Yes but the *glass* is being counted! It's half the *glass*. I've added some detail which should hopefully alleviate your confusion.

Comment: In, for example, "If I only had **half** the knowledge that he had", "knowledge" is non-count noun, but it has "half" as predeterminer modifier.

Comment: @BillJ Correct, because it's the knowledge '**he**' has. "His knowledge" is countable and quantifiable. You can say, for example "He has the knowledge of ten men", so a single person's knowledge is being quantified. Like a a glass can hold so much water, a person can hold so much knowledge.

Comment: No: "His knowledge" is **not** countable. "Knowledge" is only ever a non-count noun. It proves that "half" can be used to modify non-count nouns and NPs, which is what the OP asked about.

Comment: @BillJ I disagree. Your example has an article "half **the** knowledge". When we use 'water' or 'knowledge' as a non-count noun, there is no article - for example, "I drink water", or "I have knowledge". But we *can* count individual quantities of water, for example "**the** water in this glass". Likewise, "**the** knowledge Bill has about English" is specific and limited.

Comment: But In "I wish I had half the knowledge that he has", "knowledge" is used as a non-count noun with an article. There is no established count use of the noun "knowledge". I don't think you've thought this through enough.

Comment: @BillJ Bill, you're confused. I'm not disagreeing that 'knowledge' and 'water' are non-countable nouns, I never have. When we say "half the water" with an article we must be referring to some specific water. The fraction is applied to the quantity, not the non-count noun. It's half the glass, or half the litres, or whatever. That's why I said from the start that 'half' only works with countable nouns like glasses or litres. If you can't measure it, you can't half it; if you can measure it, then there's a measure you can half whether you mention it or not.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether or not it's some specific water; that's not what the OP's question was about. The point is that the first line of your answer, "It does only work with countable nouns" is false, as I've demonstrated with my example, where "half" is modifying a non-count NP. Likewise, "This juice is made of "half water", where again "half" is modifying a non-count noun.

Comment: @BillJ Again Bill, that's wrong, because the juice you made with half water is quantifiable. You made it in a jug. You must have measured the quantities otherwise you wouldn't know it was half. The measurements are implied, and the fraction applies to those quantities. When you use "water" without an article you don't mean that you made the juice with half of all the water in existence.

Comment: That's totally irrelevant, as I just explained. The OP's question is **Why doesn't 'half' only modify countable nouns?** The answer is that indeed it does, as I have  carefully explained to you with examples. Think syntax!

Comment: @BillJ I think you're mixing up modifiers with quantifiers.

Comment: None of your answer deals with the OP's actual question. The irrefutable fact is that despite what you say, "half" **can** modify non-count nouns, which is what the OP was on about. Consider the OP's actual question and think syntax!

Comment: If I had a tonne of coal last month, and since then I have burned 500 Kg of it in my stove, I have burned half the coal, haven't I?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes - half a tonne. You could also say "I burned a half-tonne of coal". As soon as you say 'half', you've quantified it, which is the point in my answer.

Comment: I could say 'half of the coal I had'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey You could, Mike. But again, by saying **the** coal, and by using a quantifier ('half'), you are referring to a specific, measurable amount of coal. An example of it being immeasurable would be if you said "We have a gas fire now, but when I was young, we used coal". That use of the noun 'coal' refers, not to the coal you personally used, but to substance itself. You could also say "everybody used coal".